# Lowest Common Ancestor in Java

Tags: java

I've found a solution to this problem, in this code,

```
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
    if(root == null) return null;
    if(root == p || root == q) return root;
    TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
    TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
    return left != null && right != null ? root : left == null ? right : left; 
}
```

I just can't seem to understand the last line. Can someone help me understand how the code works in the last line.

Comment: I did not down vote this, but it looks like [ternary operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). Essentially a shortcut for an `if ... else` statement (used multiple times).

Comment: Also not downvoter here, however, you should rephrase the question. Your title has nothing to do with your actual problem. It should be something like 'Nesting ternary operators'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're aware this makes use of the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java).

It might be easier to understand if you saw it surrounded with parenthesis:

```
return (left != null && right != null ? root : (left == null ? right : left));
```

Meaning, this could be rewritten as the following nested if:

```
if (left != null && right != null) {
    return root;
} else {
    if (left == null) {
        return right;
    } else {
        return left;
    }
}
```

So let's break it down. You've already checked recursively the left child sub-tree and the right child sub-tree. Now you need to decide which node you're going to return.

If both children exist (`left != null && right != null`), then the lowest common ancestor of both sub-trees is the current node, meaning the `root`, which is why you return it.

If however, one of the sub-trees doesn't exist, for instance in the following case when looking at `node2` who only has one child:

```
         root
        /    \
     node1   node2
    /     \       \
node3    node4    node5
```

Then the root cannot be the lowest common ancestor, which means it has to be in one of the sub-trees. Since one of them is `null` (doesn't exist), then it has to be in the other.

So if `left == null` then return the lowest common ancestor you've found on the right sub-tree, otherwise the right-subtree doesn't exist (is `null`) and so return the lowest common ancestor you've found on the left sub-tree.

Answer (score 0):

The [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) is used to determine which value is returned. It mighy be a bit clearer if you set braces appropriatly:

```
return (left != null && right != null) ? root : ((left == null) ? right : left);
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite the statement to use if's, which might make it a bit clearer:

```
if (left != null && right != null) {
    return root;
} else {
    if (left == null) {
        return right;
    } else {
        return left;
    }
}
```